# Delete this after cleanup

Tags: c++, this, destructor, delete-operator

```
class BaseTest {
protected:
  virtual void finalizeParts() {
      delete m_part;
  };
public:
  int* m_part;

  BaseTest() {
    m_part = new int;
  }

  void finalize() {
    finalizeParts();
    delete this;
  }
};

class SubTest : public BaseTest {
protected:
  void finalizeParts() {
      BaseTest::finalizeParts();
      delete m_anotherPart;
  }
public:
  int* m_anotherPart;

  SubTest() {
    m_anotherPart = new int;
  }
};

SubTest* test = new SubTest();
test->finalize();
```

I am having trouble avoiding virtual function calls inside the destructor of my classes (I hate that C++ forces me to do this in the first place). Overriding the destructor in all my subclasses seems terribly inconvenient compared to a common cleanup strategy in a base class using some virtual functions that can be overridden if needed. As a workaround I'm thinking about introducing a 'finalize' function in my base class that performs the cleanup and finally calls 'delete this'. It's probably a very unusual solution, so I was wondering if I'm approaching this the wrong way and if there's a more obvious way to write 'proper' destructors in C++.

Comment: A general rule to follow would be to have the object that created your object, delete it. IE. `Object A` has `Object B` as a member. `Object A` should be in charge of cleaning up after `Object B`. Another example would be you have a script that creates `Object C`. That script should be the one that cleans up `Object C`. Basically, an object should not delete itself.

Answer (score 1):

If your object aggregates other objects that manage their resources (think of smart pointers, for example. General principle is called RAII), then there is no need in destructor at all.

Of course, you still need desructor for each such "manager" but it should be much easier to implement because of less information and resources to concern about.

self-deleting in your case seems to be bad approach since no one would expect `finalize` to free object's memory (principle of least astonishment). Though it may be okay with internal implementation (For example, I once did `delete this` when was implementing shared_ptr's. Namely, I did it when counter of resource manager reaches 0. But that behavior wasn't exposed to end-user anyway)

Comment: Maybe it could be renamed `SubTest::suicide()` to help with the POLA issue?

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is wrong.

With virtual destructors, destructor of base class will be called as well as destructor of derived class - so you should implement destructor for each derived class, that would delete only relevant portion of derived class, and let destructor of base class to clean base class.

If you have a chain of derived classes, destructor for each level of inheritance will be called - in order from most derived class to the base class.

For your example, all that required is:

```
class BaseTest {
public:
  virtual ~BaseTest () {
      delete m_part;
  };
  int* m_part;

  BaseTest() {
    m_part = new int;
  }
};

class SubTest : public BaseTest {
 public:
  virtual ~SubTest () {
      //~BaseTest() will be called automatically
      delete m_anotherPart;
  }
  int* m_anotherPart;

  SubTest() {
    m_anotherPart = new int;
  }
};

SubTest* test = new SubTest();
delete test;
```

Comment: I know destructors in C++ work this way, I just don't like it. In the case of my example, if I have 50 derived classes like Subtest, every one of them that overrides finalizeParts() would need it's own destructor calling finalizeParts (which will clean up members of the baseclass as well through BaseTest::finalizeParts()). After that, should the destructor of BaseTest call finalizeParts as well? I don't see how this will work.

Comment: @DoubleDan No, the point is that you do not need virtual function finalizeParts at all - you put code of finalizeParts of BaseTest into BaseTest destructor and forget about it - it will be called for each derived class, then whatever override of finalizeParts you need for derived class you put in derived class destructors.

Answer (score 0):

Is this any simpler to you?

```
class BaseTest {
public:
  std::unique_ptr<int> m_part;

  BaseTest() : m_part(new int) {}
  virtual ~BaseTest() {}
};

class SubTest : public BaseTest {
public:
  std::unique_ptr<int> m_anotherPart;

  SubTest() : m_anotherPart(new int) {}
};

SubTest test;
```

or for that matter,

```
class BaseTest {
public:
  int m_part;
};

class SubTest : public BaseTest {
public:
  int m_anotherPart;
};

SubTest test;
```

I think you have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Instead of asking us about your weird reimplementation-of-what-destructors-already-do, ask about the problem you are having with calling virtual functions in your destructors.

Comment: The problem is not being able to use the virtual functions i already have (like finalizeParts in the example) in my destructors. These are mostly function that destroy/clean up something or remove a child object from a parent object. All of these can happen during the life of an object as well. My weird implementation allows me to use these functions in my base class 'destructor'(finalize()) while the polymorphism still works as expected. Maybe the question would have been clearer without proposing an unusual solution at the same time.